# mysql query error with four tables

Tags: mysql

i have 4 tables. `wp_users`, `ppmro_members`, `cu_orders`, `wp_posts`.
now i want to all the users which are members for that i know i can you inner join using this query

`SELECT wp_users.display_name, wp_users.user_email, cu_orders.post_id,wp_posts.post_title FROM ((wp_users INNER JOIN  wp_pmpro_memberships_users ON wp_users.id=wp_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id) INNER JOIN cu_orders  ON cu_orders.user_id =wp_users.ID  INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = cu_orders.post_id)`

and then i want to know all these users have purchased courses or not for that i need `post id` from `cu_orders` then by the `post_id` i can know the `post_title` from `wp_posts`. `user_id` and `id` is common in `wp_users` and `ppmro_members`. `cu_orders` has `user_id`, `email`, `post_id`. `cu_orders` has also the emails who are not users or members and for them `user_id` is `0`. how to do that query in mysql together?

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just add more joins to the query, in the same way as the first join.

Comment: okay sir, i am new here . i have tried many things but i wasn't working

Comment: SELECT wp_users.display_name, wp_users.user_email, cu_orders.post_id,wp_posts.post_title
FROM ((wp_users
INNER JOIN  wp_pmpro_memberships_users ON wp_users.id=wp_pmpro_memberships_users.user_id)
INNER JOIN cu_orders  ON cu_orders.user_id =wp_users.ID  INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = cu_orders.post_id  WHERE user) i have tried this but i am only getting the users who have purchased somethin

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but FWIW, I find this a little easier to read:

```
SELECT u.display_name
     , u.user_email
     , o.post_id
     , p.post_title 
  FROM wp_users u
  JOIN wp_pmpro_memberships_users x
    ON x.user_id = u.id
  JOIN cu_orders o
    ON o.user_id = u.ID  
  JOIN wp_posts p 
    ON p.ID = o.post_id
```

Comment: can you answer?